# How to add digits to a long value

Tags: java, long-integer, digit

So I have this variable `long hashvalue` and I want to add digits to it if something is true.

I have this array `int arr[3][3]` with the numbers `-1, 1, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, -1` in it

I need something like this:

```
if(array[i][j] == -1){
    //add digit 2 to hashvalue
} else if(array[i][j] == 1){
    //add digit 1 to hashvalue
} else if(array[i][j] == 0){
    //add digit 0 to hashvalue
}
```

hashvalue = 210021002

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: Hint . Make hashvalue String and then concat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply make a string for the hashvalue and adding the digits to the string via the + (or +=) operator. To receive a long object from the string, you can use the Long.parseLong() function.

```
String hashvalue = "";

// Add your digits to the String here
hashvalue += "1";

// Convert the String to a long
long finalHashvalue = Long.parseLong(hashvalue);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can just multiply hashvalue by 10 and then add the wanted digit.
Like:

```
if(array[i][j] == -1){
    hashValue = hashValue * 10 + 2;
} else if(array[i][j] == 1){
    hashValue = hashValue * 10 + 1;
} else if(array[i][j] == 0){
    hashValue = hashValue * 10 + 0;
}
```

Imagine your hashValue starts with 3, if you multiply it by 10 it becomes 30, if you add the digit, let's say 2, it becomes 32. The digit has been added. I hope I helped!